# How to sort by multiple fields in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a list that need to be sorted by 3 different fields. If it were a query I could do something like:

```
and {
    invoiceTicketDetail {
        order('date', 'asc')
        order('xrefCode', 'asc')
    }
    order('lineType')
}
```

But I already have the list like the following:

```
List<InvoiceDetail> invoiceDetailList = invoiceHeader.invoiceDetails.findAll {it.deleted==Boolean.FALSE && it.amount!=0} as List
```

How can I order to get the same result from the first one? The thing is we have two different ways to display the information. One to print on screen and one to generate a report. Both of them must show the information in the same sort.

Comment: I think the cleaner code would come out by just using criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this in your criteria:

```
{
  order('date,xrefCode,lineType','asc')
}
```

or write query:

```
Clazz.find("from Clazz order by date,xrefCode,lineType asc")
```

***Clazz*** is your domain

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by multiple conditions (fields, properties, etc) by...

1. Comparing the first property
2. If the first property comparison results in 0 (which means they're equal) continue to the next property. Otherwise, consider the two items sorted.

Here's a closure that can be curry'ed with a list of property names and then passed to `Iterable.sort(boolean, Closure)` or `Iterable.toSorted(Closure)`.

```
def sortByProperties = { List propertyNames, Object a, Object b ->
    propertyNames
        .collect { a[it] <=> b[it] }
        .find { it != 0 }
}
```

## Example

Here's how to use the closure.

```
def date1 = new Date() + 3
def date2 = new Date() - 2

def list = [
    [date: date1, xrefCode: 2, lineType: 'b'],
    [date: date2, xrefCode: 2, lineType: 'c'],
    [date: date2, xrefCode: 1, lineType: 'c'],
    [date: date1, xrefCode: 2, lineType: 'a']
]

def sortByProperties = { List propertyNames, Object a, Object b ->
    propertyNames
        .collect { a[it] <=> b[it] }
        .find { it != 0 }
}

// This form requires Groovy >= 2.4
def sortedList = list.toSorted(sortByProperties.curry(['date', 'xrefCode', 'lineType']))

// An alternative.
def sortedList = list.sort(false, sortByProperties.curry(['date', 'xrefCode', 'lineType']))
```

The output looks like this.

```
[
    [date:Tue Oct 06 20:13:13 EDT 2015, xrefCode:1, lineType:c], 
    [date:Tue Oct 06 20:13:13 EDT 2015, xrefCode:2, lineType:c], 
    [date:Sun Oct 11 20:13:13 EDT 2015, xrefCode:2, lineType:a], 
    [date:Sun Oct 11 20:13:13 EDT 2015, xrefCode:2, lineType:b]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

What I've done to solve this problem:

- Created my own comparator and when I got the list I called something like:

Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator());

Before displaying in the screen and before generating the report.
That solved my problem.